# Redirect to www in blogger

Tags: redirect, configuration, subdomain, blogger

I successfully configured a blog in blogger to a custom subdomain like www.subdomain.domain.com. The problem is that I now want to redirect subdomain.domain.com to the www.subdomain.domain.com version, but the only option that blogger give me is "Redirect domain.com to www.subdomain.domain.com" which is not what I want. I missed some configuration maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better would be to setup `subdomain.domain.com` directly . Is there any specific reason why you setup `www.subdomain.domain.com` ?